# Rails 5 + Carrierwave Upload images from mobile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, carrierwave

I wrote a rails 5 app with an api that a mobile app can call to send over a base64 encoded image to be uploaded to server, using Carrierwave gem.  The endpoint works great when I test it with Postman.  But when I try to upload an image taken with a mobile camera (whether sent directly from the app or through postman), it fails.  Carrierwave just doesn't save the image.  Does anyone have any idea why and what I can do about it?

imageuploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{mounted_as}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def scale(width, height)
    process :resize_to_fit => [width, height]
  end

  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

model.rb

```
class Log < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
  belongs_to :reward, class_name: 'Reward', foreign_key: 'reward_id'

  mount_base64_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::V1::BaseController

  def log
    @child = User.find(params[:id])
    unless @child.parent_id.nil?
      Log.create(user: @child, reward_id: params[:reward_id], image: params[:image]  )

     end
     head :ok
   end
 end
```

end

Comment: Could you show me code? Recently I have done CarrierWave image uploading from mobile phone and no issues found.

Comment: Can be memory problem.

Comment: @artgb I'm not the mobile app dev, but I added my server code.  we did test with a small image.  You think the problem is on the mobile side?

Comment: Could you show me serverside log file content? I think it's not mobile side issue.

Comment: @artgb, I feel really stupid, but the string didn't have a prefix or mime type.  I swear, the first thing I checked was that the string could be decoded.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a bad base64 string.  no prefix or mime type.  I  swear I checked!